# Can't connect to WebSocket server on remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I use the trial of PowerWebSocket API 
https://www.noemax.com/powerwebsockets/

I want connect a Client to the Server, but the server is on a remote machine.

Server

```
        var server = new WebSocketServer();
        server.AddEndpoint<LevelOneWS>("http://localhost:30000");
        server.Open();
```

Client

```
        var LevelOne = new WebSocketClient<TickService>http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz:30000);
        LevelOne.Open();
```

The port 30000 is open on the server, client, router/modem (with redirection).
But I can't connect to server, AddEndPoint cant connect, server dont accept the connection.

On the same computer, full localhost, its perfect.

Comment: Is this C#? If so, you should probably add the `C#` tag too.

Comment: yes, it's in c#. thanks

Comment: There's plenty of information on the web about how to troubleshoot network connectivity problems, usually it's a firewall blocking the connection. What have you tried?

Comment: I desactivate windows firewall on the client and server machine. Open port 30000 on the modem/router by forward port 30000 to the server computer.

Comment: I do same thing to - Clickonce, remote desktop, sqlserver, ..., and its fine.

Comment: OK, I resolve by replace localhost with local ip (192.168.1.3). Now when the client use the internet IP to contact the server its perfect

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is, that your server listens on localhost, that means the internal loopback interface: 127.0.0.1 It should listen on it's external interface.